# Visible span length using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to alert "visible" when even one span is visible. But when i am running my function it is not alerting. example code [link](http://jsfiddle.net/xTF8f/)

//script

```
if($('.none').find('span').css('display')!='none'){
alert('visible')
}
```

//html

```
<div class="none">
<span style="display:none">first</span>
<span style="display:block">second</span>
</div>
```

//css

```
.none{display:none}
```

Comment: jquery getter methods only return the value of the first element selected unless otherwise specified in the documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the parent of element is hidden then the element is automatically hidden so you will get visible count = 0 for hidden parent.

```
if($('.none').find('span:visible').length > 0){
    alert('visible');
}
```

To find out the elements will display:block

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/xTF8f/9/)**

```
visibles = $('.none').find('span').filter(function(){
   if($(this).css('display') == 'block')   
       return $(this);
});
alert(visibles.length);
```

Comment: this will not work because span parent has display none property so it never find span visible

Comment: `0` would evaluate to `false`, so the comparison isn't *entirely* necessary.

Comment: @jch: then there can be no visible elements within that element, since `none` cannot be overridden by a descendant element.

Comment: @adil: that is the exact problem, span is visible but it parent is hidden. thats why i want to get span which has display inline or display block property

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the count of the spans that have their display not set to none, however if the parent div is set to display:none, then when rendered the spans will not display, even if their display property is not set to none.

```
var cnt = 0;
$('div.none span').each(function(){
    if($(this).css('display')!='none') cnt++;
});
if(cnt>0) console.log('foo',cnt);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xTF8f/8/)**